# How would I extract all names of a similar type in a file using python and regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that is filled with cultures, and each culture has a unique set of surnames for the people of each culture. The problem I have is that there are numerous files, each of them with hundreds, if not thousands of names, so instead of gathering all of these files by hand, I would like to automate this task in a sense using python and regex.

Here is an example of the file's contents:

```
###Myrman###
360 = { # DUPLICATE §§§§§§
    name="of Myr"
    culture = myrman
}
300507 = {
    name = "of Myr"
    culture = myrman
}
300525 = {
    name = "Trellos"
    culture = myrman
}
300534 = {
    name = "Uteuran"
    culture = myrman
}

##Lysene##
1386 = {
    name="Ormollen"
    culture = lysene
    coat_of_arms = {
        template = 0
        layer = {
            texture = 14
            texture_internal = 9
            emblem = 0
            color = 0
            color = 0
            color = 0
        }
    }
}
300505 = {
    name = "of Lys"
    culture = lysene
}
300523 = {
    name = "Lohar"
    culture = lysene
}
300532 = {
    name = "Assadyrn"
    culture = lysene
}
```

So as you can see, there are two types of cultures here, each with different surnames for people of the respective cultures. I want to take all of these different names, and sort them into different groups, that are also separated by commas and quotes. Here is an example of what I want to happen:

```
Myrman: ["of Myr", "of Myr", "Trellos", "Uteuran"]

Lysene: ["Ormollen", "of Lys", "Lohar", "Assadyrn"]
```

How would I go about doing this with python and it's regex library?

Comment: Where did you get that file? It's obviously a structured format, so it'd be easier to find a parser for it rather than try to cobble together something with regexps.

Comment: Whats the file extension?

Comment: Hi, it's just a regular text file. These are files from a mod for the game "Crusader Kings 2", but these files are structured in the same way as the game's normal files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh, a parser problem! Let's use the [lark parser generator](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to figure this out.

First, let's create a syntax for our file - this is cobbled together [based on the JSON parser example](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_tutorial.html):

```
import lark

parser = lark.Lark(r"""
start: (term)*
term: key "=" value "\n"
key: CNAME | SIGNED_NUMBER
value: CNAME | SIGNED_NUMBER | ESCAPED_STRING | map
map: "{" (term)* "}"
%import common.CNAME
%import common.ESCAPED_STRING
%import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
%ignore /#.*/
""")
```

Pretty straightforward; the file is a list of `term`s, which are key-values, where the key may be a name or a number, and the value can be a name, number, string, or a map, which is a brace-enclosed list of terms.

Then, let's write a transformer to transform the Lark parse tree to a dict:

```
class TreeTransformer(lark.Transformer):
    def start(self, items):
        return dict(items)

    def term(self, items):
        return (items[0], items[1])

    def CNAME(self, item):
        return item.value

    def SIGNED_NUMBER(self, item):
        return int(item.value)

    def ESCAPED_STRING(self, item):
        return item.value[1:-1]

    def map(self, items):
        return dict(items)

    def key(self, item):
        return item[0]

    def value(self, item):
        return item[0]
```

Could probably be more terse, but this works.
Let's run it against the data:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

data = Path("./so75472097-data.txt").read_text()
tree = parser.parse(data)
res = TreeTransformer().transform(tree)
pprint(res)
```

The output is

```
{360: {'culture': 'myrman', 'name': 'of Myr'},
 1386: {'coat_of_arms': {'layer': {'color': 0,
                                   'emblem': 0,
                                   'texture': 14,
                                   'texture_internal': 9},
                         'template': 0},
        'culture': 'lysene',
        'name': 'Ormollen'},
 300505: {'culture': 'lysene', 'name': 'of Lys'},
 300507: {'culture': 'myrman', 'name': 'of Myr'},
 300523: {'culture': 'lysene', 'name': 'Lohar'},
 300525: {'culture': 'myrman', 'name': 'Trellos'},
 300532: {'culture': 'lysene', 'name': 'Assadyrn'},
 300534: {'culture': 'myrman', 'name': 'Uteuran'}}
```

-- that looks promising!

Then, it's just a matter of dict traversal:

```
from collections import defaultdict
names_by_culture = defaultdict(list)
for info in res.values():
    names_by_culture[info["culture"]].append(info["name"])
pprint(dict(names_by_culture))
```

... and hey voilà!

```
{'lysene': ['Ormollen', 'of Lys', 'Lohar', 'Assadyrn'],
 'myrman': ['of Myr', 'of Myr', 'Trellos', 'Uteuran']}
```

Now, all you have to do is wrap that bad boy into a function and call it on all of your files.

(EDIT, now that I read the latest comment and know what to google: you could just use [the ClauseWizard library](https://github.com/Shadark/ClauseWizard) instead of writing the parser yourself, but this was more fun!)

### EDIT 2

As discussed in the comments, a grammar and transformer that's also fine with "basically anything" for unquoted values:

```
parser = lark.Lark(r"""
start: (term)*
term: key "=" value "\n"
key: KEYNAME | SIGNED_NUMBER
value: VALUENAME | SIGNED_NUMBER | ESCAPED_STRING | map
map: "{" (term)* "}"
VALUENAME: /[a-zA-Z][^\s=]*/
KEYNAME: /[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*/
%import common.ESCAPED_STRING
%import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
%ignore /#.*/
""")

from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter


class TreeTransformer(lark.Transformer):
    start = dict
    map = dict
    key = itemgetter(0)
    value = itemgetter(0)
    VALUENAME = attrgetter("value")
    KEYNAME = attrgetter("value")
    term = tuple

    def SIGNED_NUMBER(self, item):
        return int(item.value)

    def ESCAPED_STRING(self, item):
        return item.value[1:-1]
```

Comment: Hey, first-off, I want to say thanks for your very thorough explanation and assistance, I appreaciate it greatly! Anyways though, I tested your code and it works, I only have one other question though, how would I let this parser parse names with special characters like: Crom-Ya or K'Mool? These names are in the file and I received an error when running it, after removing them it worked, but how would I parse names with special characters like that?

Comment: Also, I will also check out those parsers you suggested, but I do agree writing your own code is much more fun haha

Comment: If they're not quoted strings, you'd need to adjust this to use something other than CNAME for them - maybe just define a `NAME: /\w+/` sort of terminal?

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalk I edited in something that can deal with e.g. `culture = ly'sene` :)

Comment: Hey man, Thanks for all of the assistance and effort with this post, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is well structured, just use regex with the appropriate query and treat the tuples that are outputted accordingly.

```
result = re.findall('name[ ]*=[ ]*"([A-z ]+)"\n[ ]+culture[ ]*=[ ]*([A-z]+)', a)

names_by_culture = {}
for i in result:
    name = i[0]
    culture = i[1] 
    try:
        names_by_culture[culture].append(name)
    except:
        names_by_culture[culture] = []
        names_by_culture[culture].append(name)
        
print(names_by_culture)
```

Output:

```
{'myrman': ['of Myr', 'of Myr', 'Trellos', 'Uteuran'],
 'lysene': ['Ormollen', 'of Lys', 'Lohar', 'Assadyrn']}
```

Comment: Hi, I marked user AKX's post above as solved, but this is also very useful. I greatly appreciate the help!